# Window Gridview cell merge in C#.net

Tags: c#, gridview, forms

How can I merge equal cell values of Gridview   in C#.net window form.
Should I use two grid views?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "merge"

Comment: I'm using Datagrid in my Windows Forms. Some criteria same name is repeated. That situation i would like to merge cell and combine into single name. How can i merge column cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for me :)
here is the one what I found..

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/593dgvgroupedcell/dgvgroupedcell.html