# Merge distinct Cells in gridview - c#

Tags: c#

http://bytes.com/attachments/attachment/2155d1251048605/db_preview.jpg
[image]

According to the above image. 
How can i Show the table (Preview) in datagridview.

Comment: what technology we are talking about WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET ?

Comment: Same Problem with [Window GridView Cell Merge in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264807/window-gridview-cell-merge-in-c-net/4373320#4373320) and there is a simple solution for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested grid views, there are number of methods to do that. Google "nested gridviews"

Answer (score 0):

You can create the 2nd table, with the sport and game id only and the players cells empty, and manually insert the players in the last column, by creating another 3-row table inside each players cell.